# RNNs: backprop loss from just the last time step or every single one?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation, forward-backward

Consider a simple task that predict the next alphabets based on previous ones using RNNs. That is, during model inference, we would like the model to output `y1_hat` (hopefully 'b') given 'a', and `y2_hat` given ['a', `y1_hat`], etc. in a recursive manner.

In order to do this, I can think of two simple training settings which are different in data preparation and loss calculation (thus the gradient/update during backprop through time)

1. preparing the data pair as `x, y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']`;
2. preparing the data pair as `x, y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']`.

Note that I consider three time steps, for illustration. Please see the figure below for clarity; the top and bottom refer to the first and later setting, respectively, and they are the unrolled RNNs. We can substitute `x1`, `x2` and `x3` in the figure with 'a', 'b' and 'c'; `y1`, `y2` and `y3` with 'b', 'c' and 'd'. Black and red arrows represent forward and backward propagation, respectively.

One of the essential differences between the two configurations would be the loss computation for each training sample: for the first, only the loss derived from the last time step is used for gradient and weight update; while in the second, the total loss equals to the sum of losses derived from all the three time steps.

Regardless of such a difference, we can achieve the model inference scenario described earlier with both training configurations. However, I suggest there might be another differences in terms of, e.g., predicting performance; maybe the first setting would need longer input (longer than three in this example) in order to output meaningful prediction, while the second can more successfully capture both long- and short-term relation?

Any thought is appreciated, thanks!

[image: Unrolled RNNs of different settings for a same task]

Answer (score 1):

In my research going down the rabbit hole of ways to structure/train RNNs I found that it gets difficult to say if one way works better than another because results could be problem specific. I tried these two methods and they seem to converge to about the same minimum, but the first one gets there faster since it simply takes less operations on back prop. Here is a question I had where I came to similar conclusion - that multiple approaches can get the same result, but one might be faster than another.  [Truncated Back Propagation of LSTM with K2 > K1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278806/truncated-back-propagation-of-lstm-with-k2-k1)

On a side note, if you use the first approach it will be important that if your first training pair is

> x, y = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']

then your next pair needs to be

> x, y = ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['e']

rather than

> x, y = ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']

to make sure every target value is used. The 2nd method might not be bothered too much by this, but for the first one it is important.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I'd like to make clear: so with the hop size of data sampling being one (first and second pair x being ['a', 'b', 'c'] and ['b', 'c', 'd'], respectively), both configurations reach a common performance; but the first one is faster, correct? If so, we can on the other hand use a larger hop size in the second configuration, leading to a smaller dataset which in turn compensates the training time, with similar performance compared to using hop size one in the first config., right?

Comment: this is something I actually started to ponder as I wrote out my answer. Unfortunately I never tested this out but I think you could probably find a middle ground where both reach the same minimum at about the same speed.